# Android kotlin plugin 1.5.0 doesn'r recognize newest Duration API

Tags: android, kotlin

In our Android app, I just upgraded the kotlin plugin to 1.5.0.
In top level build.gradle.kts:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0")
```

And in app build.gradle.kts:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.0")
```

Now, when building, I get a bunch of deprecation warnings about the Duration API used in such statements:

```
@ExperimentalTime
val myVal = 2.seconds
```

Warning says: 'seconds: Duration' is deprecated. Use Duration.seconds() function instead.

OK, so I proceed with the replacement like asked:

```
val myVal = Duration.seconds(2)
```

Now, the seconds() method appears in red in Android Studio with the error message: Expression 'seconds' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

It seems somehow that Android Studio is mixing Kotlin 1.5 with 1.4 I guess. Is there somewhere else than the two mentioned libraries on top that should be changed to point to kotlin 1.5?
I've tried invalidating the cache and remove all build folders without success.

Comment: did u try `2.seconds()` instead ?

Comment: In kotlin 1.5, seconds() is a method of the companion object of the Duration class, so it must be called like this: Duration.seconds(2)

Comment: have you enabled 1.5 plugin in android studio? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/install-eap-plugin.html

Comment: the import package should be something like `kotlin.time.Duration` just verify that whether u have imported the correct duration class or android one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Jetbrains on the Kotlin reddit, despite some 1.5.0 artifacts being available on maven central repo allready, Kotlin 1.5.0 is not yet officially released. Some bits and pieces are missing among others the IDE plugins, which explains the problem.
https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/n0gt0d/is_kotlin_150_released/